# Django framework installation

Tags: python, django, windows-7-x64

I have installed django framework with Python 2.7 and created all the paths. The problem is that whenever I type

> django-admin.py command

the file itself is opening up. I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type

```
python django-admin.py command
```

If you get an error saying 'python is not recognized as an internal or external command..' you also need to add the python path to your environment path.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.py` files are not associated with python, so it gets treated as a normal txt file. You can either:

```
python django-admin.py command
```

(and see @VladSchnakovszki answer for errors which might pop up with that command), Or configure the files by right clicking > Properties, then (under General options):

[image]

Point it to python.exe and tell it to associate all files with the same extension with python as well.

P.S. a personal recommendation: When working in a windows environment I've had a good experience with installing [ActiveState Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython). It automatically sets the required paths, and also installs pip and other goodies that you'll probably need along the way (don't be scared of the priced version, there's a free community version too).

Comment: Hey i did like you said now for whichever command i type with django-admin.py (like django-admin.py --version) only the django-admin.py command's output is produced...

Comment: Even when you type `python django-admin.py --version`?

Comment: yup the output for python django admin.py --version is python cant open this file

Comment: That's... odd. I have no idea what might cause that. To my best of knowledge I would suggest you delete the entirety of the python folder and reinstall everything from scratch (install active state then pip install django like I showed)